# MultiByteToWideChar() и TTF_RenderGlyph_Solid

Tags: c, unicode, sdl2

Как увязать **MultiByteToWideChar()** и **TTF_RenderGlyph_Solid**?

Например, функция **TTF_RenderGlyph_Solid()** просит код символа юникода в виде 16-ти битного беззнакового целого.

Насколько я понимаю, при переводе символа из **ANSI** в **UTF16-LE** может возникнуть две проблемы:

1) Символ юникода окажется представлен суррогатной парой - двумя 16-ти битными значениями. Если это окажется так, то подскажите, как определить, что в результате использования функции **MultiByteToWideChar()** получилась суррогатная пара?

2) Даже если получившийся символ **UTF16-LE** окажется представлен одним 16-ти битным значением, может возникнуть проблема. Я не совсем понимаю, какой символ просит функция **TTF_RenderGlyph_Solid()**.

Обычный символ **UTF16-LE**, который представлен **не в виде суррогатной пары**? В этом случае 16-ти битное значение не сможет иметь любой код [0; 65535], потому что некоторые биты используются для сообщения о том, что символ представлен в виде суррогатной пары.

Или же функция **TTF_RenderGlyph_Solid()** просит код, все значения которого могут указывать на символы [0; 65535]? Тогда это уже не символ **UTF16-LE**.

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: `ANSI` - это американский институт стандартизации. Возможно тут имелось ввиду `ACII`, однако при переводе из `ACII` проблем быть не может, так как символы могут иметь код только до 127. Проблемы могут быть при переводе из каких-нибудь редких символов многобайтовых кодировок. Но тут проблема будет даже просто найти шрифт, в котором есть такие символы. А с интерфейсом функции все понятно - она принимает валидные двухбайтовые символы.

Answer (score 0):

В документации к функции [сказано](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC46), что она принимает на вход загадочный UNICODE:

```
 SDL_Surface *TTF_RenderGlyph_Solid(TTF_Font *font, Uint16 ch, SDL_Color fg)

font
    Font to render the glyph with. A NULL pointer is not checked. 
text
    The UNICODE character to render. 
fg
    The color to render the glyph in. This becomes colormap index 1.
```

Поэтому, копаем глубже и смотрим в [сорцы](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/file/8c0d97042815/SDL_ttf.c#l1524):

```
SDL_Surface *TTF_RenderGlyph_Solid(TTF_Font *font, Uint16 ch, SDL_Color fg)
{
    Uint16 ucs2[2] = { ch, 0 };
    Uint8 utf8[4];

    UCS2_to_UTF8(ucs2, utf8);
    return TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid(font, (char *)utf8, fg);
}
```

И тут становится очевидным, что под UNICODE подразумевалась кодировка UCS-2, в которой, на символ отведено только 2 байта и никаких суррогатных пар не поддерживается.

Так же, можно заметить, что в этой функции происходит перекодировка символа в UTF-8, т.е. в вашем случае это лишняя работа. Раз уж у вас исходный текст не в UCS-2, то лучше сразу перекодировать его в UTF-8 и вызывать функцию `TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid` напрямую, без промежуточной перекодировки в UCS-2.